# Implementing Nashorn ClassFilter equivalent

Tags: java, java-8, nashorn

Using the nashorn library `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.*` one can implement the `ClassFilter` interface to disable instantiating any class from within a javascript run in Java:

```
private static class NoJavaFilter implements ClassFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean exposeToScripts(String s) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works when you start the engine like so:

```
NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
ScriptEngine nashorn = factory.getScriptEngine(new NoJavaFilter());
```

But I'm using built-in Java 8 `javax.script` library:

```
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
```

That doesn't have `ClassFilter`, any thoughts how to implement the equivalent?

**UPDATE**

This code runs in a Wildfly 14 EJB container. The JsUtils bean is injected in the invoker, that runs the `run` method sending the script as a parameter.

```
@Stateless
public class JsUtils {

    public String run(String script) throws ScriptException,
                                            NoSuchMethodException {     

        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");                  
        Object result = engine.eval(script);
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you only have the `ScriptEngineManager` interface available at the time you need to use the engine. I guess the question then is how does the `ScriptEngineManager` get initialized in your application? Looking over the javadoc, it seems you can register alternative `ScriptEngineFactory` objects. You could create your own `ScriptEngineFactory` under a name like "nashorn-safe". If the `NashornScriptEngineFactory` is available at initialization, it could even decorate that.

Comment: The `ScriptEngineFactory` creates `ScriptEngine` classes, the ones used to run the scripts. Instead, what I'm looking for is a way to create a `ScriptEngineManager` class telling it to filter Java classes. By looking at the javadocs I couldn't figure this out. Also, I couldn't find any examples using both the `ScriptEngineFactory` and the `ScriptEngineManager`.

Comment: `ScriptEngineManager` has `registerEngineName()` and related methods for registering your own factory. The SEM uses the registered factory to construct the particular `ScriptEngine` associated with the name. That registration happens somewhere in your application already, perhaps implicitly.

Comment: `ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager(); sem.registerEngineName( "nashorn-filter", new NashornScriptEngineFactory(){ ScriptEngine getScriptEngine(){ return super.getEngine( NoJavaFilter(); } } );`

Comment: However you may have constraints on when `ScriptEngineManager` is created or have to share one across the app; that's why I was asking about different places and times of use.

Comment: I tried to use the code you posted, but I get a compilation error: `An anonymous class cannot subclass the final class NashornScriptEngineFactory`

Comment: Ok, so you can't extend by subclassing, but you can still solve using a decorator. I've held off giving an official answer with running code because you haven't provided details on the structure of the application and the lifecycle of use for these various engine objects as yet, and that will change the solution. We don't need proprietary detail, but we do need to understand the constraints more precisely. Cheers.

Comment: Please see updated questionk

Comment: Thank you. What exactly stops you constructing the `NashornScriptEngineFactory` directly in that use?

Comment: That was my plan B, I first tried to use `javax.script` as it's the latest library.

Comment: So, answering your immediate question, given that the use of the engine and the initialization etc is all in the same place, and absent further constraints, it seems fine to me to use it directly. 1/n

Comment: javax.script is not a new engine as such. It is an interface abstracting the use of arbitrary script engines (not just Javascript, could be others). This has existed since Java 6 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_for_the_Java_Platform

Comment: It is good practice to develop against interfaces rather than implementations where possible. This allows future variation. In the case of javax.script, this has turned out to be a very practical concern. The actual engine shipping with the Oracle JDK switched from Rhino to Nashorn in Java 8, and now in JDK 11 Nashorn is being ditched entirely. https://jaxenter.com/nashorn-deprecation-interview-caldwell-146951.html

Comment: So future maintainers of this application will have to watch this space closely regardless. Oracle has also of course withdrawn free support for Java 8. 4/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting` library, there's no other way